# Stored procedure to accept order & order by column as parameters and then sort table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to sort sql table by passing order and order by as a parameter, the same is working for column type datetime but for string and int type it is giving default sort data. below is my stored procedure

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SearchCity]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @cityname varchar(50),
    @orderby varchar(50),
    @order varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    if(@order = 'asc')
    begin
        SELECT id,city,status,CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),modifiedDatetime,6) as Date from cityMaster where city like '%'+@cityname+'%' order by case when @orderby = 'city' then city End,
case when @orderby='status' then status end,
case when @orderby='modifiedDatetime' then modifiedDatetime end asc
    end
    else if(@order ='desc')
    begin
        SELECT id,city,status,CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),modifiedDatetime,6) as Date from cityMaster where city like '%'+@cityname+'%' order by case when @orderby = 'city' then city End,
case when @orderby='status' then status end,
case when @orderby='modifiedDatetime' then modifiedDatetime end desc
    end



END


GO
```

kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Change your `@Order IF Else` as below:

For Ascending order postfix `asc` is optional, so i haven't put in code

```
DECLARE @tblTemp AS Table(
    Id INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Status INT
)

if(@order = 'asc')
begin
        INSERT INTO @tblTemp
        SELECT id,city,status,CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),modifiedDatetime,6) as Date 
        from cityMaster where city like '%'+@cityname+'%' 
        order by 
            case when @orderby = 'city' then city End,
            case when @orderby='status' then status end,
            case when @orderby='modifiedDatetime' then modifiedDatetime end 
end
else if(@order ='desc')
begin
        INSERT INTO @tblTemp
        SELECT id,city,status,CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),modifiedDatetime,6) as Date 
        from cityMaster where city like '%'+@cityname+'%' 
        order by 
            case when @orderby = 'city' then city End desc,
            case when @orderby='status' then status end desc,
            case when @orderby='modifiedDatetime' then modifiedDatetime end desc
end

SELECT * FROM @tblTemp
```

Comment: now further to this i wish to insert the result into the #tmp_table but it throws error like "Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_SearchCity, Line 35
There is already an object named '#tmp_table' in the database."

Comment: find the link for my latest code http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/w8wAfS5n8

Comment: IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_table') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp_table

Comment: write above line of code above the if(@order = 'asc')

Comment: got it, because you tried temp table to insert two location, for above scenario you have to take table variable not temp table

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic sql as the below:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SearchCity]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @cityname varchar(50),
    @orderby varchar(50),
    @order varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
        SELECT 
            id,
            city,
            status,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),modifiedDatetime,6) as Date 
        from 
            cityMaster 
        where 
            city like ''%' + @cityname + '%'' 
        order by ' + @orderby + ' ' + @order

    execute sp_executesql @Query

END
```